# Large schematic handling

Tags: support

I want to ask a question which has relatively wide schematic that would not be legible at the width allotted to SE questions.

Is there a way I can post the schematic so that readers will be able to view the wide image?

Comment: Are you suspecting the whole schematics is actually needed, or could maybe the portion of interest be cropped out? I somewhat have the feeling that if it needs the whole big schematics, it is in the domain of "too broad" anyways.

Comment: In this case the whole schematic is needed because I am asking about a modification to the system that a person will need to see most of the schematic.

Comment: Host your schematic as a large image and put the link to the image in your text ?

Comment: @MaximGi I can certainly link outside to an image. The problem with this is that eventually any outside link will probably no longer work, then future readers of the question will not be able to see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This markdown syntax makes the picture clickable:
`[![description][1]][1]`
When clicked, it behaves like an ordinary image file in your browser.

Example:
[image: description]

Comment: That worked. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 2):

A while ago the image uploading changed. It will now automatically scale the picture (via html width / height code), and make it linkable to itself so that it can be seen full size by left clicking, no right clicking needed.

Ask your question using the normal image uploading, and if it is insufficient for the large image, we'll figure something out.

Answer (score 1):

Use `imgur` to host the image. SE has a tight relationship with them, and that's the service you get when you hit ^G (or click the little mountain range icon) while editing your post. The image will be scaled to fit the question, but any interested reader can right-click on it to see the full resolution.